# how to install sshfs in centos 8 from repository using package manager tool

Tags: centos

I am install sshfs using this command in CentOS 8, but it not worked:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dnf install sshfs
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:53 ago on Sat 11 Jul 2020 07:59:03 AM EDT.
No match for argument: sshfs
Error: Unable to find a match: sshfs


[root@localhost ~]#  dnf install fuse-sshfs 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Sat 11 Jul 2020 08:04:40 AM EDT.
No match for argument: fuse-sshfs
Error: Unable to find a match: fuse-sshfs
```

is there possible to install it from repo?

Comment: I have the exact same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the package is called `fuse-sshfs`, not `sshfs`.

Second, you need to first enable the PowerTools repo if you haven't already.

```
yum-config-manager --enable PowerTools
```

Last, install `fuse-sshfs`

```
yum install fuse-sshfs
```

Comment: simplest way: yum --enablerepo=powertools install fuse-sshfs . That should it. Or you can go this way, but yum-config-manager may not be installed by default, add it using yum install yum-tools. The repo is currently called "powertools" (case sensitive). Alternatively, just configure it by enabling it in /etc/yum.repos.d/.